# how to use RGB values in feedforward neural network?

Tags: python, image, pytorch

I have data set of colored images in the form of ndarray (100, 20, 20, 3) and 100 corresponding labels. When passing them as input to a fully connected neural network (not CNN), what should I do with the 3 values of RGB? Average them perhaps lose some information, but if not manipulating them, my main issue is batch size, as demo-ed below in pytorch.

```
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # because of rgb values, now images is 3 times the length of labels
        images = Variable(images.view(-1, 400))
        labels = Variable(labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

This returns 'ValueError: Expected input batch_size (300) to match target batch_size (100).' Should I have reshaped images into (1, 1200) dimension tensors? Thanks in advance for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since size of labels is `(100,)`, so your batch data should be with shape of `(100, H, W, C)`. I'm assuming your data loader is returning a tensor with shape of `(100,20,20,3)`. The error happens because you reshape the tensor to `(300,400)`.

1. Check your network architecture whether the input tensor shape is `(20,20,3)`.
2. If your network can only accept single channel images, you can first convert your RGB to grayscale images.
3. Or, modify your network architecture to make it accept 3 channels images. One convenient way is adding an extra layer reducing 3 channels to 1 channel, and you do not need to change the other parts of the network.

Comment: current my first layer is just nn.Linear(input_nodes, hidden_nodes) with input_nodes 100. I could however make my input data (100, 400*3). I wonder if that makes sense. And how can i reduce 3 channels to 1 channel (ideally not adding layers)? is it averaging R, G & B? thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to convert rgb to grayscale images. [This](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) would be useful. One takeaway is simply averaging three values (R+G+B)/3

Comment: Thanks. Newbie question: what would be the reason not to make it 400*3?

Comment: You can do this. But usually, fully connected layer will introduce more parameters than conv layer.

Answer (score 1):

Use Grey scaled image to reduce the batch size